# which of these libs are standard J2EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am building a enterprise JAVA EE api website. This website need to suit JAVA EE spec. Which means I can't use Spring, Hibernate...etc. Although this website uses Spring and Hibernate. Which means I have to remove the related code and use standard JAVA EE library. 
Following are some libs we use right now. Can anyone tell me which libs are standard JAVA EE? Or show me how to know whether a lib is JAVA EE standard. THX.

```
javax.inject   
com.googlecode.gentyref
org.springframework   -> not 
org.apache.httpcomponents
org.apache.log4j
ch.qos.logback
org.slf4j
redis.clients
org.hibernate   -> not
commons-io
org.apache.commons
commons-beanutils
mysql-connector-java
org.glassfish.jersey
com.fasterxml.jackson
javax.servlet  -> JAVA EE
org.apache.oltu.oauth2
```

Comment: When you downloaded J2EE, what libraries did you get?

Comment: "J2EE" is an obsolete acronym. Java EE includes JPA, so why is Hibernate not allowed? Have you looked at the Java EE documentation?

Comment: " website need to suit JAVA EE spec" - IMHO it means you have to leverage the J2EE API, but nothing prevents to use 3rd party implementations and their dependencies. (ok, except Spring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked for clients like this before.

Assuming that you will be moving to a fully Java EE 7 compliant server, the biggest issue you will have is whether or not the existing application uses Spring MVC. There is no current alternative to this and you would need to either:

1. Rewrite using Java Server Faces (JSF)
2. Rewrite using JAX-RS (REST) and build a rich JavaScript front end.

And given that, you would remove all of jars that you have listed above and just use the [standard Java EE 7 API](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/javaee-api/7.0/javaee-api-7.0.jar), which you can include using maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

This jar includes all of the standard APIs that you have in your list above.

You will also need to decide what do about redis and the Apache oauth support.

Hibernate can reasonably easily be migrated to standard JPA.

Logging can be replaced by `java.util.logging`.

Comment: THX. Can I use Jersey? As I know, Jersey is JAVAEE, but it seems not included in this jar?

Comment: You would not use Jersey directly. The [javax.ws.rs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/package-summary.html) and [javax.json](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/package-summary.html) packages provide your REST support. Many server implementations use Jersey to implement these.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some hard limits forcing you to remove any of this dependencies?

Just to make an example. `org.apache.log4j` isn't a JEE library. But there's no strict rule telling you to remove it from a JEE application. You can happily use log4j in every JEE application.

*Using Spring* means nothing. Spring offers a lot of tools that are fully JEE compliant.

My guess is that your sponsoner want's to make sure that your application is running on an JEE application server. A list of jars does not mean a lot in this context.

Comment: The sponsor want us to use J2EE. They stopped our project once just because we used Spring. So We want to know that which libs are not JEE before we give our proposal. I know it's very difficult to construct a program like this...

Comment: Does your sponsor know that nobody is doing J2EE apps at the minute?

Comment: Does this mean you can't use `java.util` classes? Those aren't Java EE.

Comment: java.util is not JEE. lol OMG.  Excuse me, how do u know java.util is not part of JEE?